Azure DevOps MSBuild Task path not supported
running MS build task using wildcard search for my csproj file. File gets found but I get the following error
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(322,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(D:\a\1\a /p:platform=AnyCPU /p:configuration=Production /p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_31eadf19-8753-47e7-ab71-358ee84b0b15_build_1812_0 \)" cannot be evaluated. The given path's format is not supported. [D:\a\1\s\src\PI\PI.Express\PI.Express.csproj]
to get the path to the csproj file I've done both hardcoded $(build.sourcesdirectory)\path\to\csproj and **/myproject.csproj. both return the same result. I've tried on a self hosted and azure hosted agent. same result. project is net framework 4.7.1. and the agent VM image is windows-2019
when I go to build the solution file instead in a VS build task it succeeds. I've tried a different csproj with the same results. the csproj does have some project dependencies but I'm pulling down the entire solution. this error seems to be vague and I'm having difficulties finding solutions.
here is my task
- task: MSbuild@1
  displayName: build project
  inputs:
    solution: '**\PI.API.csproj'
    platform: 'AnyCPU'
    configuration: 'Production'


The expression in your error is "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(D:\a\1\a /p:platform=AnyCPU /p:configuration=Production /p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_31eadf19-8753-47e7-ab71-358ee84b0b15_build_1812_0 \)". I.E. you are passing D:\a\1\a /p:platform=AnyCPU /p:configuration=Production /p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_31eadf19-8753-47e7-ab71-358ee84b0b15_build_1812_0  to GetFullPath().

You don't need to find the path. The path of the current project being built is always available as the $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) property. See "MSBuild reserved and well-known properties".

i updated my question to include the task that's failing. i'm not directly passing/calling get full path.

Ah. It could be a pipeline issue. Have you turned on detailed logging for the pipeline by setting System.Debug to true? Is PI.API.csproj an SDK style or legacy style project?

Try changing the '' to '/' in the file matching pattern - e.g. '**/PI.API.csproj'

The "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath has incorrect value passed then the error reported.  It's recommended to share your csproj and repo structure. Instead of this method, try to use relative path  for a check.

The error MSB4184 message The given path's format is not supported means that there’s an issue with the format of the file path that’s being passed to the [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath method.
The D:\a\1\a /p:platform=AnyCPU /p:configuration=Production /p:_MSDeployUserAgent=VSTS_31eadf19-8753-47e7-ab71-358ee84b0b15_build_1812_0 \ part looks like a combination with D:\a\1\a and MSBuild arguments, and an extra \ at the end.
You need to check where [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath defined in your project, and how the value(path) is constructed or passed.
